# Skip columns while converting CSV file to HTML table

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am using `randomuser.me API` to generate random users CSV file.
Program is supposed to convert the CSV to HTML table.
I am trying to skip column `[0, 3, 4]` to not be shown in generated HTML Table. 
To do this I am trying to use `for-loop` and `if-condition`. 
The problem is that the variable `column` in the loop is not an `int` and I cannot create condition `if (int(column) == 0 and int(column) == 3 and int(column) == 4)`.
I would be very grateful for pointing the solution how to solve it.

```
import webbrowser
import csv
import sys
import requests

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Usage: project.py <htmlFile>")
    exit(0)

url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=2&format=csv&inc=name,picture'
with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(url)
    decodedContent = download.content.decode('utf-8')
    csvFile = list(csv.reader(decodedContent.splitlines(), delimiter=','))


 # Create the HTML file
htmlFile = open(sys.argv[1], "w")

# Fills up HTM code
# Remove BOM from UTF-8 (wierd symbols in the beggining of table)
htmlFile.write('<html><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"><head><title>Tabela</title></head><body><table>')

# Read a single row from the CSV file
for row in csvFile: 
    # Create a new row in the table
    htmlFile.write('<tr>'); 
    # For each column
    for column in row: 
        if (int(column) == 0 and int(column) == 3 and int(column) == 4):
            continue
        else:
            htmlFile.write('<td>' + column + '</td>')
    htmlFile.write('</tr>')

htmlFile.write('</table></body></html>')

webbrowser.open_new_tab('index.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `del` to remove entries from a `list`. So, in reverse order, just get rid of them:

```
for c in [4,3,0]:
    del row[c]
```

It's important to use reverse order, because deleting items from a list changes the numbering of everything after that item. So always go from the last to the first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the RandomUser API you are using, but logically, I would not expect it to be possible for the following statement to be true:

```
int(column) == 0 and int(column) == 3 and int(column) == 4
```

Can the column equal all those values at the same time?  Seems unlikely.  I would expect that the column would either be column 0 ***or*** column 3 ***or*** column 4.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Should be or statement. Bu it still doens't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

As Austin Hastings said, I deleted not needed columns in CSV file

```
for row in csvFile:
    for column in [4,3,0]:
        del row[column]
```